# Criteria : creating alias beetwen 3 entities

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I couldn't find better questions so I hope it shows what I am asking.

I have 3 entities ( i will only write code that really matters for better reading

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo extends BaseEntity{
[...]
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.foo")
    private Set<FooDooRel> Doos= new HashSet<FooDooRel>();
[...]
}
```

**FooDooRel.java**

```
public class FooDooRel implements IEntity {
@EmbeddedId
private FooDooRelId pk;
[...]
}
```

**FooDooRelId.java**

```
public class FooDooRelId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "doo_id")
    private Doo doo;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Foo foo;
}
```

**Doo.java**

```
public class Doo extends BaseEntity{
[...]
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.doo")
    private Set<FooDooRel> Foos= new HashSet<FooDooRel>();
@Column(name = "dispid", nullable = false)
    private String dispid;
[...]
}
```

Now I have to create Aliases for my filter so

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Foo.java, "foo")
criteria.createAlias("Doos", "Disp5", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq(Disp5.pk.foo.dispid", "5"));
```

Now first error, when I do this i get this error

> could not resolve property: pk.foo.dispid of: pl.FooDooRel

I understand i have to do second JOIN to join FooDooRel with Doo but I dont know how to do this. I can create alias for FooDooRel but how, in the same criteria go further to Doo.

second one, i have to do 2 aliases from same Set when I do this

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Foo.java, "foo")
criteria.createAlias("Doos", "Disp5", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq(Disp5.pk.foo.dispid", "5"));
criteria.createAlias("Doos", "Disp6", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq(Disp5.pk.foo.dispid", "6"));
```

I get an error, that path is duplicated

So first, how can I join FooDooRel to Foo by checking dispid in Doo, and second how can I join 2 aliases from same path?

Comment: Your posted code isn't syntaxically correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote this code here, so meaby I forget about something (yes dispid unique is little weird..), but I didn't want to write question that will "take" whole page. My entities and embaddable are working just fine, I only wanted to write little example of 3 of them connectem to eachother. My main issue is creating Aliasses, if you be so nice I would be glad to write what more do you need to help me resolve my issue. Cheers, and sorry for my english.

Comment: If you still would like to help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193538/hibernate-criteria-creating-alias-with-entity-through-another-entity-with-embed) is link to my similar question with all data's you probably need. Since I don't know how to BUMP my question i made another one.